# Can I avoid object creation in a if?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if I put an object creation in a `if`, will it take resources even if the `if` isn't true?

For example, in the following code:

```
if (foo) {
    doSomething({
        option1: aVeryLongCallToGetThisValue(),
        option2: idem()
    });
}
```

If `foo` is false, will JS optimize it and skip the creation of the object containing option1 and option2 (this snippet is supposed to be called many times)? Furthermore `option1` and `option2` depend on the context (imagine a variable passed to `aVeryLongCallToGetThisValue` so I can't compute it once for all beforehand.

Comment: Yeah, it won't go down the path if foo is false

Answer (score 0):

> If `foo` is false, will JS optimize it

That's not so much optimization as it is basic execution semantics. That is, conditional execution is just what `if` does. If the condition is not true, none of the statements in the `if` body are executed and none of its effects happen.

This is true in all programming languages. It's a very fundamental feature.

Comment: Yes. However, this doesn't mean branches that are never reached are as if they weren't there. Whether a branch is executed or not is only known at run-time. For example: string literals found in those branches would still be interned; static allocations would still happen, etc. A JavaScript object literal is dynamically allocated, so in this case it won't be.

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ What do you mean by "interned" and "static allocations"?

Comment: Non-JS concepts (Java and C respectively), but mentioned them because you referred to all programming languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable